# WP_Query twice on one page - not getting the desired posts per page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type which has an ACF check box to define if an post is featured or not. I wanted to show 6 featured and 6 non featured posts on a page and so created 2 WP_Query loops both with separate args. Whilst the separation of featured and non-featured is working, the page only shows 6 posts in total and I'm not sure how to resolve that?

My code:

```
        <?php
            $args1 = array(
            post_type       => 'fairs',
            posts_per_page  =>  -1,
            showposts       => 6 ,
            meta_key        => 'start',
            orderby         => 'meta_value_num',
            order           => 'ASC'

            );
            $new1 = new WP_Query($args1);?>
            <?php while ($new1->have_posts()) : $new1->the_post();?>
                <?php $field = get_field( 'wa_feature', get_the_ID() ); if ( true == $field ):?>   
                    Featured Posts
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();?>

        <?php
            $args2 = array(
            post_type       => 'fairs',
            posts_per_page  =>  -1,
            showposts       => 6 ,
            meta_key        => 'start',
            orderby         => 'meta_value_num',
            order           => 'ASC'

            );
            $new2 = new WP_Query($args2);?>
            <?php while ($new2->have_posts()) : $new2->the_post();?>
                <?php $field = get_field( 'wa_feature', get_the_ID() ); if ( false == $field ):?>   
                    Non-featured Posts
               <?php endif;?>
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WP_Query` isn't right. You do two completely identical queries `($args1 = $args2)`, and expects diffrent results from them. Also you put `meta_key` into query arguments, but without telling what and how to compare.

Depending on what type you have chosen, the right syntax, if your meta filed is named `featured` and the query can be:

```
args1 = array(
  'post_type'       => 'fairs',
  'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
  'meta_key'        => 'featured',
  'meta_value'      => true //or 1, or 'yes` depending of ACF type you have choose 
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'           => 'ASC'
);

args1 = array(
  'post_type'       => 'fairs',
  'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
  'meta_key'        => 'featured',
  'meta_value'      => false//or 0, or 'no` 
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'           => 'ASC'
);
```

or if this `featured` field exists only in `featured` posts then

```
args1 = array(
  'post_type'       => 'fairs',
  'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'           => 'ASC'.
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'featured',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
     ),
   )
);

args1 = array(
  'post_type'       => 'fairs',
  'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
  'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'           => 'ASC'.
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'     => 'featured',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
     ),
   )
);
```

Check [ACF query](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) or [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for the right sintax.

Comment: theresults or the query aren't the issue, that side of things is working just fine. The problem I'm having is that despite having 2 queries which should show 6 results each, I'm getting 2 queries which show 6 results between them

Comment: I shouldnt have been so quick to dismiss you!! taking the if statement out of the look and adding a meta query in the array has worked!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments should be quoted:

```
array(
    'post_type'       => 'fairs',
    'posts_per_page'  => 6,
    'meta_key'        => 'start',
    'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'           => 'ASC'
);
```

Array keys can either be integers, or strings. Read more in the [PHP `array()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

You should also only use `posts_per_page` in this case (and remove `showposts`, which was [replaced by `posts_per_page` in WP 2.1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)).